# How to define custom primary key in sequelize-cli with custom name

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

```
    sequelize model:create --name tasks --force --attributes "title:string,description:text, data_type:text, shift:str
ing, date:date, start_time:time, end_time:time, type:string, location:string, visible_to_helpers:date, reminders_to_helpers:integer, created_date:time, modifi
ed_date:time"
```

I tried this. It's working but it create primary key with `id` which I want to some task_id

But when i tried this its giving me error

```
    equelize model:create --name tasks --force --attributes "task_id:{type:integer, primaryKey: true,autoIncrement:
true}, title:string,description:text, data_type:text, shift:string, date:date, start_time:time, end_time:time, type:string, location:string, visible_to_helpe
rs:date, reminders_to_helpers:integer, created_date:time, modified_date:time"
```

and also not working in case of all small letter

Thanks

here is the error

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I solve it in hacky way. After creating the model(like your first command), it make id as the primary key. So i update the model, "something else" as my primary key and run the command below:

```
node_modules/.bin/sequelize db:migrate
```

It worked for me. Here is a link of guidelines I followed:

http://mherman.org/blog/2015/10/22/node-postgres-sequelize/#.WWUr49MrIsk